# Connection refused while connecting to Solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr6

I am in process for setting up Solr-6 in cloud mode and I started Solr server with command -

> bin/solr -e cloud -noprompt

IP to which solr was bound was - 15.xxx.xxx.103.
I restarted my server the next day it is picking up and trying to connect to above IP address only. I have a dynamic IP address and currently my IP is - 15.xxx.xxx.194. The error on console is -

```
    ERROR: Failed to create collection 'gettingstarted' due to: {15.xxx.xxx.103:7574_solr=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:Server refused connection at: http://15.xxx.xxx.103:7574/solr,
    15.xxx.xxx.103:8983_solr=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:Server refused connection at: http://15.xxx.xxx.103:8983/solr}
```

Operating System being used - OSX LCapitan 10.11.6

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the address in question is reachable and the ports open? Also, zookeeper will hold node information based on the ip. Since that has changed, you are unable to connect. Try either manually renaming the zookeeper nodes to point to your new up or set up a hostname and use that instead of the ip